# how to change div orientation on small screen in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am working on bootstrap and i am stuck in a div orientation on small screen. 
on medium screen i am using 6, 6 columns which should stack on top of each other on small screen[i want something list this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsUMC.png)

on small screen the columns are going like column 3 on top of column 4, but i want column 4 on top of column 3. how can i do that? i know it has to do something with push pull, but i am unable to figure it out

EDIT: i am currently using this code, which needs to be modify like the layout in the picture i have shared above

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            column 3
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            column 4
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is this 1,2 and 4,3 on small screen ?

Comment: yes i want it like 1,2 and 4,3 instead of 3,4

Comment: Please post some code that we can inspect.

Comment: i have edited the question. kindly have a look

Answer (score 1):

using `flex` , just add it to your `@media` css query.

```css
.container>.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">





<div class="container">
<h1>Flex:</h1>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            column 3
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            column 4
        </div>
</div>
</div>

<h1>normal</h1>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            column 3
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            column 4
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is tagged for **Bootstrap 4**

Comment: its also tagged `css` @Klooven, this is a solution, if you have a better one please help the guy.

Comment: It's a completely valid solution for BS3, but this can be made using only classes included in BS4. It's of course the asker that selects the solution that works best for him/her :)

Answer (score -1):

Use float right property on 3 and 4 and put 4 before 3. it will automaticallty show 3,4 on big screen and 4,3 on small screen

Comment: are you sure its the right way? I mean isn't there a solution in bootstrap?

Comment: Use bootstrap pull-right class.

Comment: @ShadowWalker Nope, this is not the right way for Bootstrap 4. Please check the duplicate questions for the right way.